# url rewriting using .htaccess giving CSS error

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website with url `mydomain.com/about.php?see=help`

I want to rewrite it to some simple url.

I rewritten it to be `mydomain.com/help.htm` using the following code written at my .htaccess file which works perfectly fine.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)\.htm$ about.php?see=$1
```

But I want to use mydomain.com/about/help I'm using the following code to achieve it but it gives error. The page is opening properly but it doesn't include my css file due to which a page without any css styles opens.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule about/(.*)/ about.php?see=$1
RewriteRule about/(.*) about.php?see=$1
```

Please tell me what is wrong.

Note: all files of my website including the CSS file are in same home directory of my website.

Comment: Use absolute paths for css/js/images.

Comment: thanks very much @anubhava... it worked absolutely fine...